# Nifi : JSON to .csv file transformation

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, execute-script

I have a following input in Nifi Jolt Specification processor, that i got from an API :

```json
{
  "BAG": {
    "Ett": "WWWLOG",
    "refD": "DVJOB1415738",
    "TO": "JOB",
    "tst": ""
  },
  "TC": {
    "Command": "DVJOB1415738",
    "dateCmd": "20/11/2026 10:25:16",
    "codeTransporteur": "999",
    "RProjet": "62165SUN_XXXXX_XXXXXX"
  },
  "buyer": {
    "id": "929292",
    "CMDM": "867220 SAN ANDREAS",
    "Exp": "021",
    "refB": "CIN1887881",
    "lieuL": "867220"
  },
  "CntShip": {
    "TC": "2",
    "cleR": "WWW",
    "FN": "ITASM",
    "LN": "DATA1",
    "Phone": "07********",
    "mail": "data.iteam@xxxx.net"
  },
  "LC": [
    {
      "N": 1,
      "CArt": "3561920920832",
      "CArtDAPO": "",
      "Q": 1
    },
    {
      "N": 2,
      "CArt": "3561920936604",
      "CArtDAPO": "",
      "Q": 1
    },
    {
      "N": 3,
      "CArt": "2619000120519",
      "CArtDAPO": "",
      "Q": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

and from this input I want to get such output as a flatfile:

```
11|SHIP2023112009251776006143|WWWLOG|DVJOB1415738|WWW|OFFER|JOB||20251120102517|
12|SHIP2023112009251776006143|WWWLOG|DVJOB1415738|DVJOB1415738|20231120092516|999||929292|867220|||867220 SAN ANDREAS|021|||CIN1887881|
15|SHIP2023112009251776006143|WWWLOG|DVJOB1415738|2|WWW|ITASM|DATA1|07********||data.iteam@xxxx.net|
8|SHIP2023112009251776006143|WWWLOG|DVJOB1415738|1|3561920956992|||1|||1||||62165SUN_XXXXX_XXXXXX||||||
8|SHIP2023112009251776006143|WWWLOG|DVJOB1415738|2|3561920936604|||1|||2||||62165SUN_XXXXX_XXXXXX||||||
8|SHIP2023112009251776006143|WWWLOG|DVJOB1415738|3|2619000120519|||1|||3||||62165SUN_XXXXX_XXXXXX||||||
```

- i Don't know if i use only JoltTransformation is enough to get this output, or i need to use others processors.

1. while the first number in each line represent the level of the attribute for each line in our json file: for exemple **11=Bag, 12="TC & buyer", 15=CntShip , 8=LC** for each article.
2. the "**SHIP2025112010251776006143**" represent the "**MSG_N**" is should be generated by me using this form "**SHIP+yyyyMMddHHMMSS+8randomNumbers**" and be the same in all line of the output.
3. The seconde and the third and 4th field should be the same for all the line in the output.
4. The fields that is not empty but it wasn't mentionned in the input json file should be added after, like the six field in the first line "**OFFER**" or the 17 Field in the second line is also has to be generated by us
5. the empty field "|||" that we have in our output represent a field in our excel file for the mapping, so even if their empty they should be added to the output,because they exist in our mapping file and represent more attribute.

So Please, Can you explain me how I can produce such an output ?

Comment: Jolt is a library that converts from a JSON value to another one. So, you should use some other processor(s) such as `EvaluateJsonPath` and `PutFile`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for reaching out, yeah i already thought that only using jolt won't be enough, am still beginner in nifi that's why i posted about how can i reach the output, what steps that i have to follow to get the final output

Comment: Once you have a working spec for JSON-to-JSON, you can use JoltTransformRecord instead of JoltTransformJSON and choose a CSVRecordWriter